# Redirecting to same page with different url name in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Basically I have a page User.cshtml.I want to use this page for both admin and user but with different url.How do i do it?

```
       $scope.ReDirectToProfile = function (loginContactId) {
         $window.location.href = '/Admin/Users?param=MjUw
      };

      <a href="#" ng-click="ReDirectToProfile(loginContactId)">Profile</a>
```

This is  what I am doing.When user click on profile.It should redirect to 'www.example.com/Admin/Users?param=MjUw'; but  in browser the url should be seen as www.example.com/Profile?param=MjUw.

Comment: Why didn't copy paste same thing for both pages, and change what you want?

Comment: you can also create two different routes with different url but use the same html and controller in the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using asp.net MVC architecture. It can be done by two different route for same ActionResult mathod which is rendering View.